# cannot get-caller-identity from another default region

Tags: amazon-web-services, sts

I am troubleshooting an issue about sending SMS (SNS service) in another region because this service is not available in my region.

So, I need to switch my AWS_DEFAULT_REGION to somewhere else.

I following command work well

```
bash-5.0# aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AROAUUXXXXXXIYUL4OIJU:botocore-session-1642736552",
    "Account": "318462213682",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::311234567890:assumed-role/eksctl-tst-backend-eks-addon-iamserviceaccou-Role1-K6RXXXXX51XX/botocore-session-1642736552"
}
```

But after I switch to another region it does not work anymore

```
bash-5.0# export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-1
bash-5.0# aws sts get-caller-identity

Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL: "https://sts.amazonaws.com/".
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: looks like it's been blocked by the firewall

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853089/aws-s3-cli-connection-was-closed-before-we-received-a-valid-response-from-endp

Comment: If that's a firewall issue, why it can run with unchanged region? Does the STS endpoint sts.amazonaws.com would route to different IP based on my "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" setting?